# Cable connected but no internet access on a virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I don't know if someone here can help me with this here but I will try.

I'm using VirtualBox to try Ubuntu, and everything worked correctly, the first, second and third time I installed it, using the iso. But some days ago, when I decided to install it again, there was no internet connection, and in the upper right corner on the internet icon there was a question mark (?).

There are several network modes and the one that I was using is NAT, the default. I'll leave an explanation of what it is below. (Taken from https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/)

> This network mode is enabled for a virtual network adapter by default.
> A guest operating system on a VM can access hosts in a physical local
> area network (LAN) by using a virtual NAT (Network Address
> Translation) device. External networks, including the internet, are
> accessible from a guest OS. A guest machine is not accessible from a
> host machine, or from other machines in the network when the NAT mode
> is used for VirtualBox networking. This default network mode is
> sufficient for users who wish to use a VM just for internet access,
> for example.
>
> The IP address of the VM network adapter is obtained via DHCP and the
> IP addresses of the network used in this network mode cannot be
> changed in the GUI. VirtualBox has a built-in DHCP server and NAT
> engine. A virtual NAT device uses the physical network adapter of the
> VirtualBox host as an external network interface. The default address
> of the virtual DHCP server used in the NAT mode is 10.0.2.2 (this is
> also the IP address of the default gateway for a VM). The network mask
> is 255.255.255.0.
>
> If you configure the network adapters of two or more VMs to use the
> NAT mode, each VM will obtain the 10.0.2.15 IP address in its own
> isolated network behind a private virtual NAT device. The default
> gateway for each VM is 10.0.2.2. In VirtualBox IP addresses are not
> changed when the NAT mode is used, as you can see below:
>
> [NAT mode diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Umdx.png)

There is also other mode called Bridged Adapter, that basically makes the Virtual Machine behave as if it was a computer connected to your physical LAN. (Explanation below: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/)

> This mode is used for connecting the virtual network adapter of a VM
> to a physical network to which a physical network adapter of the
> VirtualBox host machine is connected. A VM virtual network adapter
> uses the host network interface for a network connection. Put simply,
> network packets are sent and received directly from/to the virtual
> network adapter without additional routing. A special net filter
> driver is used by VirtualBox for a bridged network mode in order to
> filter data from the physical network adapter of the host.
>
> This network mode can be used to run servers on VMs that must be fully
> accessible from a physical local area network. When using the bridged
> network mode in VirtualBox, you can access a host machine, hosts of
> the physical network and external networks, including internet from a
> VM. The VM can be accessed from the host machine and from other hosts
> (and VMs) connected to the physical network.
>
> If you have multiple physical network adapters on the host machine,
> you should select the correct adapter in VirtualBox network settings.
>
> In VirtualBox, the IP address of a VM virtual network adapter can
> belong to the same network as the IP address of the physical network
> adapter of the host machine when the bridged mode is used. If there is
> a DHCP server in your physical network, the virtual network adapter of
> the VM will obtain the IP address automatically in the bridged mode
> (if obtaining an IP address automatically is set in the network
> interface settings in a guest OS). Thus, the default gateway for a
> virtual network adapter operating in the bridged mode is the same as
> for your host machine. Let’s look at a simple example with IP
> addresses.
>
> The address of the physical network: 10.10.10.0/24
>
> The IP address of the default gateway in the physical network:
> 10.10.10.1
>
> The IP address of the DHCP server in the physical network: 10.10.10.1
>
> IP configuration of the host machine: The IP address – 10.10.10.72;
> netmask – 255.255.255.0; default gateway – 10.10.10.1.
>
> IP configuration of the guest machine: The IP address – 10.10.10.91;
> netmask – 255.255.255.0; default gateway – 10.10.10.1.
>
> [Bridged adapter diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzSYQ.png)

When I use bridged mode, I have complete internet access, but when i use NAT I can't access the internet. I can still ping the host machine and Google (8.8.8.8) and other sites using the ip address, but not the url. So I'm thinking this might be a DNS problem.

I don't know what kind of info I could also provide, to help someone solve the problem, but just ask if you need to know something more.

Edit: I had already asked the same question on VirtualBox's forums: [here is the post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=102253).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Were this an Ubuntu DNS issue, it would occur on both NAT and Bridged. This smells like a Host settings issue to me.

Comment: @user535733 Wdym? Something in windows (my host) or in virtualbox settings?

Comment: Correct. One of those.

Comment: Do you know what it might be?